# How to find threshold value and which wavelet family to use for low pass filter signal?

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing, wavelet

I am trying to implement the code on this website [ http://ataspinar.com/2018/12/21/a-guide-for-using-the-wavelet-transform-in-machine-learning/ ] where it looks into applying low pass filter to signal, however, I can't understand how he got the threshold value and wavelet family. Can you explain how he came up with value and wavelet name?

For the code:

```
def lowpassfilter(signal, thresh = 0.63, wavelet="db4"):
    thresh = thresh*np.nanmax(signal)
    coeff = pywt.wavedec(signal, wavelet, mode="per" )
    coeff[1:] = (pywt.threshold(i, value=thresh, mode="soft" ) for i in coeff[1:])
    reconstructed_signal = pywt.waverec(coeff, wavelet, mode="per" )
    return reconstructed_signal
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

In this case the threshold value of 0.63 means that he wishes to maintain only 63% of the lower frequencies in the signal. Since higher frequencies generally aren't crucial to the total energy of the signal, you can argue for their removal for the sake of compression. Depending on the signal, you could remove up to 99% of it and still get a perfect inverse transform.

As for his selection of the Daubechie 4 wavelet, I don't know what else to say besides the fact that it's a pretty common wavelet to see. It can estimate pretty well polynomials of degree 3 which is usually good enough for most applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after looking into the code, I want to understand the general use of the modes in "wavedec" and "threshold".

Comment: @Momo I direct your attention to these pages: [wavedec modes](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/signal-extension-modes.html#ref-modes) & [threshold modes](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/thresholding-functions.html)

Comment: I will look into it, I just have another question, I have been through articles which implement wavelet to used for feature extraction. However, some articles were saying that they select a certain level (for example, lvl 5 of detail coefficient) as input to use for extracting statistical features. How is it possible to decide which level to use for feature extraction?